# LINQ to SQL dmbl generation remove tables

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is there a way to tweak the LINQ to SQL generation not to generate the GetTable<> methods and the Insert/Update methods?

Comment: An option could be this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31519/LINQtoSQL-Customize-the-Code-Generated-by-the-Desi